# Error when creating interpreter in Pycharm from Conda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, interpreter

I made a new environment in Anaconda and I want to add it as a new interpreter in Pycharm. However, when I go to make it I get the following error.

C:\apps\anaconda3\envs\web\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\apps\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.1\jbr\bin\create': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I checked my files and it looks like there is no 'create' file where it is looking, but I am not sure what to do. I have added interpreters this same exact way from other conda environments in the past, so I am not sure if the create file was deleted somehow or what. Do I need to make a new 'create' file?